# ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in jquery-ui-1.8.17 codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am getting an error **ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined in jquery-ui-1.8.17**. I tried to change code to `jquery-ui-1.8.16` but that is also not working.

My template view is as follows:

```
    <head>
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="<?php echo base_url('theme'); ?>/images/icon.jpg">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title><?php echo $title;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('theme/css');?>/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('theme/js');?>/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('theme/js');?>/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

can any one help me ??

Comment: jQuery is not defined when you included jQuery UI. you must include jQuery first, and not more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/and-jquery-not-defined-problems
 can help you out. maintaining the order can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

you need to include jQuery base library first, and then you can include custom.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('theme/js');?>/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your include scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('theme/js');?>/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>theme/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
```

include jQuery before adding jQuery-ui